# Linq Group by and Order by

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a sql query where I group by `Name` and then order by `Date`.
I would also need to select only one entry per group with the newest Date.
How do I do that in linq (using lambda expression)?

```
select Name,Date,Comment 
from Feedback
Group by Name,Date,Comment
order by Date desc
```

My linq

```
var query= db.Feedback
                .GroupBy(f => f.Name, (f, g) => new
                {
                    Name = f,
                    Comment = g.Select(h => h.Comment),
                    Date= g.Select(h => h.Date)
                })
                .Select(f => new { f.Name, f.Date, f.Comment}).ToList();
```

How to sort each group by `Date` desc and take the first entry?

**EDIT**

I have updated my query to

```
    var query= db.Feedback.GroupBy(f => new { f.Name, f.Comment })
                .Select(a => a.AsEnumerable())
                .Select(b => b.OrderByDescending(f => f.Date)
                .Select(c=>new{c.Name,c.Date,c.Comment}));
```

...and doing the last Select prevents having reference loop error in JsonSerializer.

*My Data should look like this*

Name:Name1
Date:28 Sept
Comment:comment text

Name:Name2
Date: 15 Aug
Comment:comment text

*...but it looks like that:*

Name:Name1
Date:28 Sept
Comment:comment text

Name:Name2
Date: 15 Aug
Comment:comment text

Name:Name1
Date: 01 Aug
Comment:comment text

...AND HERE IS THE SOLUTION

```
        var query= db.Feedback
                .GroupBy(f => new { f.Name})
                .Select(a => a.AsEnumerable())
                .Select(b => b.OrderByDescending(f => f.Date)
                    .Select(c => new { c.Name, c.Date, c.Comment})
                    .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Do you want the first element from each group?

Comment: Yes, by newest Date.

Answer (score 6):

Your query would be:

```
var query= from f in db.Feedback
           group f by new {f.Name, f.Date, f.Comment} into g
           orderby g.Key.Date descending
           select new {g.Key.Name, g.Key.Date, g.Key.Comment};
```

Also:

```
var query= from f in db.Feedback
           group f by new {f.Name, f.Date, f.Comment} into g
           orderby g.Key.Date descending
           select g.Key;
```

And if you want the firs element, use `FirstOrDefault` extension method:

```
var first= query.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want the first element of each group ordered by `Date` then you can also do this:

```
var query= from f in db.Feedback
           group f by new {f.Name, f.Date, f.Comment} into g
           select g.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to group only by name then do the following:

```
var query= from f in db.Feedback
           group f by f.Name into g
           select g.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I would like to take the newest Date/Comment item which is grouped by Name. FirstOrDefault() will give me the first item for entire query.

Comment: @agri, check now my answer

Comment: ..since the actual database has references to other tables I get "Self referencing loop detected". How to break the loop?

Comment: There are several ways to do it, [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Loop-Reference-handling-in-caaffaf7) you will a lot. An easy way is disabling lazy loading and proxy creation in your context

Answer (score 3):

You can not apply `GroupBy` and then `OrderBy` on Date column. Because if you have it in `GroupBy` it will give you only one Date value in each group. So if you want to order by Date, you should remove it from group by and use this:

```
var q = db.Feedback
            .GroupBy(f => new {f.Name, f.Comment})
            .Select( a => a.AsEnumerable())
            .Select(b=> b.OrderByDescending(f => f.Date))
        ;

foreach (var item in q)
{
    Debug.Log(item.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Since the Date is type datetime in database it gives me "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable" error